# Appending html tabe with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add row in html table stored in database. I am using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) with MySQL.

Here is function:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
function addRow() {
    //Connect to database and set charset
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webapp");
    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
    
    //Connection check
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) { exit("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }
    
    //Selects html from MySQL and fetch it in array
    $postContent = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=1");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($postContent);
    
    //Creates new simple html dom object
    //and loads html from $result as first value from array
    $html = str_get_html($result[0]);

    //Change inner html of <tbody id="CZ">
    $html->find("tbody[id=CZ]", 0)->innertext = '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
}
?>
```

Here is my html from MySQL:

```
<table border="1"><tbody id="CZ"></tbody</table>
```

If I run It I get this error `Attempt to assign property of non-object in /function.php on line 21` where line 21 is:

`$html->find("tbody[id=CZ]", 0)->innertext = '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';`

How can make it work or could you tell me any advice how should I append table in database?

Thank you in advance

edit: replaced part of code with Jacobson's code. Still getting `Attempt to assign property of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($result[0]);
```

with this

```
$html = str_get_html($result[0]);
```

Still, make sure that $result[0] is actually returning your html table from database.

Comment: Problem is that I am getting `Attempt to assign property of non-object` error. I dont know why because I used this to change html before and it worked.